# How to enable Nunit tests to run only on Linux OS (and don't run on Windows)?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm using Nunit for testing My Program (The tests run automatically when we doing build to the program).

The program runs on both Windows and Linux operation systems, and I have some tests which supposed to run only on Linux Os. Is there some way to make sure those tests will run only on Linux and not on Windows OS?

I know That in JUnit for exmaple there is possibility to add the title @EnabledOnOs(LINUX) , but I could not find something similar to Nunit.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: `[Platform("Linux")]`

NUnit will generate a reason but if you want a more detailed one, you can specify it.

```cs
[Platform("Linux", Reason="Only runs on Linux because... ")]
```

You may use this on methods or on an entire fixture class.